# VueJS: Check if property has value from another property

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm currently learning Javascript (VueJS) and updated one of my existing Laravel apps. It worked pretty well so far. Still I'm in trouble at one point: I have two props (e.g. prop1 and prop2) and want to render an entry in a table differently, if a value in prop1 is also present in prop2, meaning the value is somewhere in prop2. Look at this sample code:

```
<tr v-for="s in list">
    <td v-if="s.value1 is also present in prop2"><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i></td>
    <td v-else><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i></td>
    <td>{{ s.value1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ s.value2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a nice and short "vue-like" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .some operator to check if a value is present in another array:

```
// Will return true if any items matches s.value1
prop2.some(function (item) {
    return item === s.value1
});
```

You can add it to your Vue instance as a method or a computed property, for example:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue",
    data: {
      prop2: []
    },
    methods: {
      checkProp2: function(val) {
        return prop2.some(function (item) {
          return item === val;
        })
      }
    }
})
```

Then you can do something like:

```
<tr v-for="s in list">
    <td v-if="checkProp2(s.value1)"><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i></td>
    <td v-else><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i></td>
    <td>{{ s.value1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ s.value2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<td v-if="s.value1 === s.value2">
```

Comment: it says "also present" so I guess that the equal comparisson is not enough

Comment: Then OP should explain what "also present" should mean exactly.